how does this code work? all balanced permutations from codewars
I met this problem in codewars and I do not understand the solution from other users.
This is the question

Write a function which makes a list of strings representing all of the ways you can balance n pairs of parentheses

Examples
balanced_parens(0) => [""]
balanced_parens(1) => ["()"]
balanced_parens(2) => ["()()","(())"]
balanced_parens(3) => ["()()()","(())()","()(())","(()())","((()))"]

My solution involves using itertools permutations to get all permutations from input and adding them to a list. However, this will use up too much memory once n gets to 10.
this is the solution from another user.
def balanced_parens(n):
    '''
    To construct all the possible strings with n pairs of balanced parentheses
    this function makes use of a stack of items with the following structure:
        (current, left, right)
    Where:
        current is the string being constructed
        left is the count of '(' remaining
        right is the count of  ')' remaining
    '''
    stack = [('', n, 0)]
    result = []

    # Loop until we run out of items in the stack
    while stack:
        current, left, right = stack.pop()

        # if no '(' or ')' left to add, add current to the result
        if left == 0 and right == 0:
            result.append(current)

        # if we can, add a '(' and return to the stack
        if left > 0:
            stack.append((current + '(', left - 1, right + 1))

        # if we can, add a ')' and return to the stack
        if right > 0:
            stack.append((current + ')', left, right - 1))

    return result

I do not understand how this code will cycle through all permutations.
From my understanding, I know that this code will add a '(' while in the loop, and a ')' when there is an open '('. So n=3 will return '()()()'
But how does it cycle through the rest, eg '((()))'?
i tried looking through the comments for this answer. Other than saying that this is a very elegant solution, not much else was said. I was not able to understand much from chatgpt either.

Whenever there is an ( on the end of the string, it does add a ), but it ALSO adds another ( as a possibility - so you end up with both (( and (). On the next cycle using (), it adds ()( - but then it adds both ()(( and ()(). By continually building the string with both ( and ) as possibilities (branches) and storing the result once it has used 3 ( and 3 ) in any combination, it builds all possible permutations. If you have the ability to debug the Python (for example, in Visual Studio Code), put a breakpoint on the stack.pop() line and watch stack grow.

The solution does a few things:

it recognises that the number of ( matches the number of ), so it keeps track of how many ( to add, and increments the number of ) to add by one whenever it adds a (.
it builds the solution from left to right, and for every position adds a continuation with ( to the stack if there are ( left to add, and a continuation with ) if there are ) left to add.
it loops until the stack is empty, which will happen after every combination of parentheses for which left and right are both 0 - that is, all needed ( have been added, and there are no ) left to add either.

If you keep track of stack during the iterations for n == 3:
[('', 3, 0)]
[('(', 2, 1)]
[('((', 1, 2), ('()', 2, 0)]
[('((', 1, 2), ('()(', 1, 1)]
[('((', 1, 2), ('()((', 0, 2), ('()()', 1, 0)]
[('((', 1, 2), ('()((', 0, 2), ('()()(', 0, 1)]
[('((', 1, 2), ('()((', 0, 2), ('()()()', 0, 0)]
[('((', 1, 2), ('()((', 0, 2)]  # '()()()' to result
[('((', 1, 2), ('()(()', 0, 1)]
[('((', 1, 2), ('()(())', 0, 0)]
[('((', 1, 2)]  # '()(())' to result
[('(((', 0, 3), ('(()', 1, 1)]
[('(((', 0, 3), ('(()(', 0, 2), ('(())', 1, 0)]
[('(((', 0, 3), ('(()(', 0, 2), ('(())(', 0, 1)]
[('(((', 0, 3), ('(()(', 0, 2), ('(())()', 0, 0)]
[('(((', 0, 3), ('(()(', 0, 2)]  # '(())()' to result
[('(((', 0, 3), ('(()()', 0, 1)]
[('(((', 0, 3), ('(()())', 0, 0)]
[('(((', 0, 3)]  # '(()())' to result
[('((()', 0, 2)]
[('((())', 0, 1)]
[('((()))', 0, 0)]
[]  # '((()))' to result

So, the result will be:
['()()()', '()(())', '(())()', '(()())', '((()))']

You can see how this would work for any n.
It's elegant, in that the code only has clear instructions that systematically work through all the solutions, it doesn't need recursion (and thus is safe for large n), and the result is predictable. It's not necessarily the fastest or most efficient solution - but readable code is often better than efficient code.
After giving it some thought, I like this solution:
def parens(n: int) -> list[str]:
    solutions = {0: ['']}
    for i in range(0, n):
        solutions[i+1] = [
            f'({a}){b}'
            for j in range(i+1)
            for a in solutions[j]
            for b in solutions[i-j]
        ]
    return solutions[n]

